# Summary of results in Access report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I haven't used Access in about 10 years and need to do a simple report for a 1 time problem.  I have a report that displays employees' work history. It is grouped nicely by name already, but what I would like to do is a summary above the full report of names that meet the search terms. How would I do this in Access 2k7

i.e.

```
-------------------------  | 
These employees were found |
Bob                        |
Joe                        |-Part I would like to add to the report
Steve                      |
Alan                       |
-------------------------  |
Name:
Bob
-------------------------
Work history 1
Work History 2
Work history (n)

Name:
Joe
-------------------------
Work history 1
Work History 2
Work history (n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom VBA function that loops through a recordset and builds a concatenated string to output.  Below is a button that opens a report, read comments for the general strategy

```
Private Sub OpenReport_Click()
    Dim searchCriteria As String
    Dim sql As String
    searchCriteria = InputBox("Input search criteria here")
    ' you can do some validation on the search criteria here if you wish

    ' creating the sql string for the record source of the report
    sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_workhistory WHERE workhistory = '" & searchCriteria & "'"

    ' opening report with blank record source
    DoCmd.OpenReport "workhistoryReport", acViewReport
    With Reports.Item("workhistoryReport")
        .RecordSource = sql
        ' assigning the control sources of the textboxes in report shouldn't be necesarry but report didn't
        ' seem to "refresh" until a control was explicitly assigned even if it is the exact same control source
        .Controls("employee").ControlSource = "employee"
        .Controls("workhistory").ControlSource = "workhistory"
    End With

    ' looping through a group by query with results of the same search criteria
    Dim rs As Recordset
    sql = "SELECT employee FROM employee_workhistory WHERE workhistory = '" & searchCriteria & "' GROUP BY employee"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)
    Do Until rs.EOF
        ' build the string you want to place on report here and assign to a text box
        ' in header of the report
        Debug.Print rs("employee")
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried adding a sub query simply selecting the name column in the query used to fill the rest of the report but then I end up entering the search criteria twice.

Comment: You should be able to link the reports using the `Master-Child` properties of the forms to avoid that.

Comment: Or you aren't referring to a field on a form (the search criteria I am assuming?) properly.

Comment: @OverMind I'm not using a form. just a query with a user defined `[search term]`

Comment: Hmm if you're comfortable with VBA you could write a couple of lines to get the search criteria into a variable and pass it to both reports behind the scenes.  From the users point of view it'll look like the same window.  Not sure if there is a more elegant way to link the parameters between queries across reports

Comment: I've modified my answer to include some code that might get you started.  I went with a different approach than what I mentioned in my comments